# Axios Interceptor returns 401 error Authorization, due to Bearer token

Tags: javascript, axios, interceptor

I want to connect logout api. With `fetch` there is no problem. Everything works. But in axios `Bearer` token does not change, it returns `null`.

My logout function

```
  let logoutUser = async () => {

    // let response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/logout/`, {
    //   method: "POST",
    //   headers: {
    //     Authorization: "Bearer " + authToken,
    //   },
    // });
    let response = await api.post("/logout");
  };
```

My axios interceptors

```
let authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken") || null;
export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: endPoint,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
  },
});

api.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
    if (token) {
      config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

I have a token. Before logout I login, and after I logout. But axios returns 401 Unauthorized. Because Bearer token is null

[image]

Login function

```
  let loginUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let response = await auth().post("/login", { email: "rahil.eliyev@gmail.com", password: "123456" });
    if (response.status === 200) {
      setauthToken(response.data.token);
      setUser(response.data);
      localStorage.setItem("authToken", JSON.stringify(response.data.token));
      navigate("/");
    } else {
      alert("Something went wrong");
    }
  };
```

Comment: Did you log the response.data.token?

Comment: @Rostami yes, I login

Comment: Did you check your browser in case your data would save in local storage or your code have the ability to access local storage?

Comment: @Rostamiyes yes I checked. The data saves in local storage, but axios takes first parameter (null) thats why Bearer token is null

Comment: Can you give me a log of response.data